# Prolog: How to make a bagof fail in the middle of execution

Tags: prolog

My problem is that I have a functor with the next structure:

```
something(Perms, New_perms) :-
    bagof(New_perm, aux_something(Perms, New_perm), <New_perms>).
aux_something(Perms, New_perm) :-
    member(Perm, Perms),
    take_impossible(Perm, New_perms).

take_impossible(Perm_poss, New_perm) :-
    Perm_poss = [Var, Perm],
    bagof(P, member(P, Perm), subsumes_term(Var, P)), New_perms),
    New_perm = [Var, New_perms].
```

This takes a list of elements of the form:

```
[[A, 2, C], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]]
```

It returns the list of possible permutations:

```
[[A, 2, C], [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]]
```

But with the list containing an impossible element:

```
[[A, 4, C], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]]
```

The functor should return false.
I need that, when it takes an element of the list which has no possible permutations, the list returns false. A forall instead of the bagof doesn't work because it doesn't change any variable bindings, and a forall before the bagof is too expensive, as I am doing the same operation to all elements of the list twice (it exceeds the limit time in the test). How can I break the execution of a bagof if the condition fails, or is there any other predicate that can do what I am looking for?

(Functor and aux_functor are not the real names of the variables, but this is college work, and so I am trying not to give too much info).

Comment: You _could_ throw an exception and catch it outside of bagof to cause an early stop of processing...

Comment: Thx for the idea, I have come with a solution from it

Comment: In this specific case, as the first list and the resulting one should have the same length, comparing them would give the solution, however, I am still interested in seeing how what I describe can be done without these specifics

Comment: you have a _predicate_, not a "functor". "functor" is a syntactic category / token type in Prolog's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid, question when I found the answer...
A bagof that fails when its objective fails is just a maplist.
Thanks for the help, anyway.
In this case, the correct answer would be:

```
something(Perms, New_perms) :-
    maplist(take_impossible, Perms, New_perms).

take_impossible(Perm_poss, New_perm) :-
    Perm_poss = [Var, Perm],
    bagof(P, member(P, Perm), subsumes_term(Var, P)), New_perms),
    New_perm = [Var, New_perms].
```

Comment: "A bagof that fails when its objective fails is just a maplist." That doesn't sound right. "bagof" collects all answers of a goal by redoing the goal until no more answers are found and succeeds if there is at least one answer. "maplist" calls a goal with an N-tuple of list elements at each position of a N-sized-vector of lists, and succeeds if all calls succeed.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I am not saying it literally, but that the most simple way to refactor the problem in order to achieve the goal is to make it with a maplist